# How to append html using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have been trying to append html data from a html file to a html page. It seems to be something very simple, but it is not working! Can you help me?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var theCitiesList="<?php echo htmlentities(file_get_contents("cityOptions.html")); ?>";
        $("select#chooseCity").html(theCitiesList);                 
    });
</script>
</head>
<body> 
    <FORM id="searchForm">
        <h2>Selecione uma cidade: </h2>            
        <select id="chooseCity"></select>
    </FORM>
</body>  
</html>
```

cityOptions.html is basically a long list of cities such as:

```
        <option value="" selected></option>
        <option value="1">California</option>
        <option value="2">New York</option>
```

Comment: Instead of require, check out file_get_contents instead http://us1.php.net/file_get_contents

Comment: why include two jquery (1.3.2 and 1.4.1) in one file?

Comment: @Chen-TsuLin thank u! I have just removed the oldest!

Comment: Having PHP code in a javascript variable that is then used in `.html()` won't cause the PHP code to be executed. Perhaps using jQuery's .ajax() methods you can retrieve the cityOptions.html content, and insert it?

Comment: @SLoW Sorry, what do you mean? The php require part of the code was commented! I removed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### .load() is shortcut of $.get():

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get('cityOptions.html', function(data) {
        $('#chooseCity').html(data);
    });            
});
```

Comment: @DanielTheRocketMan I have sent answer before this answer. You were able to do it with `.load()`. However, you have select longer version of `.load()`. This seems strange

Answer (score 2):

You can use JQuery [.load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/) like;

```
$("select#chooseCity").load("cityOptions.html");
```

This will load `cityOptions.html` in to your specified html area

Answer (score 0):

cityOptions.html had newlines `\n`. replacing it helps.

```
<html>
<head>       
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var theCitiesList='<?php echo str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n", "\r"), "",file_get_contents("cityOptions.html"));  ?>';
            $("select#chooseCity").html(theCitiesList);                 
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="searchForm">
        <h2>Selecione uma cidade: </h2>            
        <select id="chooseCity">

        </select>
    </form>
 </body>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it is not solving the problem. Do you think the rest is ok?